# Starting and stopping App Engine instances with Docker

Tags: google-app-engine, docker

I've set up an App Engine project locally using Docker (on OSX), and have been running a server using the usual "gcloud preview app run app.yaml" command. From what I can tell, this keeps creating new images over and over again. After an hour or so of work I end up with something like 30 docker images, each taking 130MB.

Eventually I'm told I can no longer bind to localhost:8080. I tried killing all containers and images, but still cannot use localhost:8080 until I reboot.

Seems like I'm not using Docker/gcloud correctly. Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? Is there another way I should be restarting App Engine instances other than hitting command C and running the "run" command again?

UPDATE: After looking closer, I noticed I'm getting this message when I run an app locally and a container is created: "http: Hijack is incompatible with use of CloseNotifier". I'm not familiar enough with Docker to understand what's going on here. All searches seem to point to Go, which I am not using.

UPDATE 2: Here is the trace:

```
Creating container...
INFO     2015-05-05 02:23:28,293 containers.py:560] Container 1564ce4344957114312d6d1dc696ffbb4176b40ace6dcff5e4239e13ee04a8f6 created.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/judeosborn/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py", line 643, in _ListenToLogs
    for line in log_lines:
  File "/Users/judeosborn/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/docker/docker/client.py", line 225, in _multiplexed_response_stream_helper
    socket = self._get_raw_response_socket(response)
  File "/Users/judeosborn/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/docker/docker/client.py", line 167, in _get_raw_response_socket
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/Users/judeosborn/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/docker/docker/client.py", line 119, in _raise_for_status
    raise errors.APIError(e, response, explanation=explanation)
APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("http: Hijack is incompatible with use of CloseNotifier")

INFO     2015-05-05 02:23:28,606 module.py:1745] New instance for module "default" serving on:
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I believe these are two separate issues-- the docker images retained locally for a long period, and the port staying bound under some circs when you quit.  For the second, if you do a 'ps', do you see a process running 'dev_appserver.py'?  If so, what happens if you kill that process manually?  Also, to double check -- did you mean "control-C" to quit?

Comment: You're probably right about two separate issues, though I'm guessing they are related. I can kill the process. And, yes, I mean control-C.

Comment: When you get the port binding issue, if you do a ps, do you see anything still running?  I believe you can look for 'dev_appserver'.

Comment: Yes, I can definitely kill the process. That's not a problem. I'm trying to figure out the source of the issue, though, so I don't have to keep doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an ongoing issue with Docker 1.6.x [[reference](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12845)] that prevents `gcloud` to work well with Managed VMs (as you seem to be using). Easiest workaround until it gets fixed is to downgrade Docker in your development machine to version 1.5.0, which is the latest version known to work.

For Ubuntu, you can do something like:

`$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu | sed 's/lxc-docker/lxc-docker-1.5.0/' | sudo sh`

For other Linux distros, you might have to modify that `sed` pattern, though.

---

On the other hand, if you're using Boot2Docker under Mac OS X, follow these steps:

1. Fully uninstall your previous Boot2Docker/Docker setup; there is a nice guide [here](http://therealmarv.com/blog/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-offical-docker-os-x-installation/)
2. Reinstall Boot2Docker/Docker following instructions [here](http://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/). **IMPORTANT**: You MUST stop right after completing "Install Boot2Docker" step and before "Start the Boot2Docker Application". Once you get there, open up a terminal and execute the following commands:

```bash
$ mkdir ~/.boot2docker 
$ echo 'ISOURL="https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.5.0/boot2docker.iso"' > ~/.boot2docker/profile
```

At this point, you can continue with "Start the Boot2Docker Application" section and finish the installation. You should now have a valid Docker launchpad with which to start Managed VMs. It'd be nice to double check that you have the right versions installed by issuing:

`$ boot2docker ssh docker version | egrep "(Client|Server) version"`

The output should look like:

`Client version: 1.5.0
Server version: 1.5.0`

Now you can try again your original command:

`$ gcloud preview app run app.yaml`

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for letting me know. At least I know it's not something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Indeed very helpful. However I installed 1.5.0 by selecting "Tags" on the github page and then selecting the 1.5.0 installer.

Comment: I went through the process suggested twice, and it didn't work for me.  I ended up just downloading the boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/tag/v1.5.0 and with boot2docker stopped, I coppied the iso to ~/.boot2docker/ and /usr/local/share/boot2docker/, did a boot2docker start, boot2docker ssh docker version and all was well.  1.6.2 boot2docker w/ Docker 1.5  (all worked -- this is for the Mac version)

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel What exactly didn't work for you? It's true that the goal is to have Docker 1.5 running inside boot2docker's VM, though; boot2docker itself can be 1.6.2 since that doesn't really matter

Comment: So @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel is 1.5.0 still the version of Docker we shoudl be using? I appear to be having the same problem starting a Managed VM locally that us running, we're trying to run a Grails App in it.

Comment: The current documentation says you can use 1.7.0  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/getting-started#check_your_docker_versions

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

`$ ps uax | egrep "gcloud|appserver"`

If you see anything running, `kill` it... you may even need to `kill -9` it.

Comment: As I commented above, I can kill processes just fine. That's not the problem. I'm trying to figure out why it keeps happening. It happens almost every time I cancel the devserver.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report here: [link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list)